How do I find out if I'm related to someone who shares my very rare surname?
I have a very rare surname, with a global incidence of only 51 according to forbears.io, and only 12 living people with the name in my country, according to familysearch.org. To be fair, I don't know how accurate either of these sites are, but they are consistent with my experience of never having met another person (outside of my known relatives) with my last name (or who has even heard of it before).
Years ago on a social media site, I connected with a person in another country who shares my exact name (first and last), as well as my general ethnic background. We have chatted a few times, and it seems pretty likely to both of us that we are related. But any common ancestor would probably have to be at least 3 or 4 generations back (if not much further), based on when that side of my family immigrated. How do I go about beginning to research whether we are actually related?

May we assume your surname is 'Monstera'? If not, what is it, please?
Either way, how far did you get, trying to trace your ancestors through any kind of official records and where or when did those paths dry up?

DNA testing will tell you whether a particular someone is related to you, and how distantly (within limits). Depending on the test, you might get additional information like ethnicity (but results are often confusing). Y-chromosome testing might show that there relatives on the paternal line that have other surnames.
Other avenues to pursue would be to look at historical records and naming practises: that is, researching the geographic distribution of the surname, possible meanings, and spelling variations or trends, and regional histories. You might concentrate on the genealogical records of your own relatives, or you might expand to a full surname study, building other branches and hoping to connect at some later point.
You might find that your surname spelling was unique to a particular region, because of the local dialect. Or the name may have been chosen by ancestor when surnames, instead of patronymics, were required to be taken. Or some ancestor acquired a different surname when they moved to a new city or country, or took up a new occupation. Or they deliberately changed it, because they were embarrassed by their birth surname. This research might not find more current relatives, but might help explain why the surname is so rare.

I think the easiest way to begin exploring whether you may be related is if you both undertake autosomal DNA testing at a site like Ancestry, MyHeritage, etc.
